# Submit (post) form to Java Servlet using Orbeon XForms

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, orbeon, xforms

I am trying to execute the simplest of tasks and that is to submit a form to a Java Servlet using XForms (orbeon).

```
<xforms:submission id="login-submit" ref="instance('login-instance')" resource="/Login/login.do" method="urlencoded-post" mediatype="application/xml" replace="all">
```

When I click the Submit button I get :

```
Type    class java.lang.NullPointerException
Message null
Location    oxf:/ops/xforms/xforms-server-submit.xpl
Line    73
Column  51
Stack Trace 

java.lang.NullPointerException
..
```

Along with large stacktrace. I know the servlet works as using a standard HTML form logs me in to the site. I've spent a long time on this trying to get it to work and at a loss. I'm using Orbeon v3.9.1 PE and an evaluation license, Tomcat 7.0.32, and v1.7.0_07 of the JRE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see some parameters are missing. See the below example which you can understand and accordingly use your parameter values.

```
<xforms:submission id="submission-id" ref="instance('form-instance')"
        action="http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/servlets/servlet/TestServlet" 
        method="post" replace="none"
        validate="false">
    <xforms:message ev:event="xforms-submit-done" level="modal" value="'Submission Successful'"/>
    <xforms:message ev:event="xforms-submit-error" level="modal" value="'Submission failed'"/>
</xforms:submission>
```

Test the url given in action first to see whether the servlet is configured correctly or not.

You can test your submission functionality and it is given [here](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-advanced-submissions#TOC-The-echo%3a-URL-scheme). You can add the `xforms-submit-done` and `xforms-submit-error` events to check which event is getting thrown.

Comment: I have added the missing attributes and all is well. so thank you very much. I now need to work out how to send the content of the form as plain text (standard HTML form) as I assume the default is to send an XML fragment | document. I've tried serialization="text/plain" but that doesn't work for me.

Comment: OK, I'm even more confused now. Even submitting the form in its native form how do I access it from my servlet? If I try to dump the request parameter list I get nothing out but I know the code is being called!

Comment: @user1759390: You have to call the request input stream in servlet and may be store stream content in a string or write it to a file.